# Numerical methods for the $u_t + \frac{(u_x)^2}{2} = 0$ equation

Tags: hyperbolic-pde, oscillations

I'm looking for some methods that could be directly applied to the PDE
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + 
\frac{(u_x)^2}{2} = 0\tag{*}
$$
**without** converting it by $v = u_x$ to the Hopf equation
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + 
\frac{\partial (v^2/2)}{\partial x} = 0.
$$

Ideally, a WENO scheme is perfect, but I'm wondering how to apply a limiter or a numerical flux to $(*)$.

Simple centered scheme
$$
\dot u_i(t) = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{u_{i+1}(t) - u_{i-1}(t)}{2h}\right)^2
$$
expectedly oscillates when shock (on $v = u_x$) is formed.
[image]

Comment: You have tagged this with "hyperbolic-pde", but it is really a Hamilton-Jacobi equation.  Have you read anything about discretization of Hamilton-Jacobi equations?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thank you David, I'm going to read about HJ equation now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Hamilton-Jacobi equation.  You can read about how to apply WENO to such equations in Section 4 of [Chi-Wang Shu's 2009 WENO review paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/070679065), and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest scheme you could employ is an upwind scheme. It's first-order and introduces artificial viscosity/diffusion, but doesn't require limiters. Probably the next simplest class would be Lax-Wendroff schemes, for which you can find a comprehensive explanation in LeVeque's book on Finite Volume schemes.

Comment: Can you please show me the upwind scheme for my equation? Not for the Hopf form, but for the original one.